# How can I do the same thing as "netsh trace start" when "capture=yes" specified by calling EnableTraceEx2?

Tags: c++, winapi, tcp, etw, netsh

I want to capture packets via ETW using the Microsoft-windows-TCPIP provider.

When I use "netsh trace start capture=yes Provider=Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP" to capture packets, I can found the TCP traffic payload in the etl file.

But if i don't specify the "capture=yes" keyword, i can't found the TCP packet payload in the etl file.

Then i tried using the Win32 APIs to start a trace to capture the TCP traffic. I called StartTrace and EnableTraceEx2, and i got the same result as "netsh start trace" that not specified the "capture=yes" keyword, and no TCP packet payload in the etl file.

I want to know what the netsh did when "capture=yes" specified, and what should i do to do the same thing as netsh when "capture=yes" specified by calling Win32 APIs.

Thank you.

Comment: I would look at the documentation. What does it say?

Comment: I can't find the detail about "capture=yes" in the document of netsh:

Comment: `netsh trace start /?`: "Defaults: capture=no (specifies whether packet capture is enabled in addition to trace events)"

Comment: I looked at the `EnableTraceEx2` without getting wiser. But evidently it has to do with filters, if it's supported. I suggest you explore that.

Comment: I know how to use netsh to manage trace, but I want to do it myself by using win32 APIs. I can't find any information in msdn about how to start a trace session with "capture=yes" option by calling win32 APIs myself.